# Typescript - calling class methods inside constructor decorator

Tags: typescript, decorator

I have a class with constructor decorator, which apply additional properties.
In this decorator, I calling class method through constructor prototype.

```
function classDecorator(params: any) {
    return function <T extends { new(...args: any[]): {} }>(constructor: T) {
        constructor.prototype.someFunc();

         return class extends constructor {    
            // add new properties...
        } 
    }
}
```

And the class:

```
@classDecorator("someParams")
class SomeClass {
     someProp: string;
     otherProp: string = "otherProp";

     constructor(val) {
         this.someProp = val;
     }   

     someFunc() {
          console.log(this.someProp);
          console.log(this.otherProp);
     }
}
```

When I created instance of this class:

```
let obj = new SomeClass("someth");
```

then method "someFunc()" called inside decorator, but both properties "someProp" and "otherProp" are undefined.

It seems it is because method was called but properties not initialized yet.

Is some correct way to call class methods from constructor decorator in such case?

Any help will wonderful.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The decorator gets executed once when the class is declared when no instance of the class exists. If you want to access instance fields /methods when an instance of the class is created you can override the constructor and execute code there after the base constructor has been executed

```
function classDecorator(params: any) {
    return function <T extends { new(...args: any[]): { someFunc(): void } }>(constructor: T) {
        return class extends constructor {
            constructor(...args: any[]) {
                super(...args);
                this.someFunc();
            }
        }
    }
}

@classDecorator("someParams")
class SomeClass {
    someProp: string;
    otherProp: string = "otherProp";

    constructor(val) {
        this.someProp = val;
    }   

    someFunc() {
        console.log(this.someProp);
        console.log(this.otherProp);
    }
}

let obj = new SomeClass("someth");
```

Comment: @StanislavKharchenko don't forget to upvote and mark as answered if it was helpful. Maybe also on the previous answer I gave as well ;-)

Comment: It runs fine with `esbuild` but it will throw error using Typescript compiler. Because a decorator could apply to any generic class, in this case the Decorator apply on an Anonymous class, which doesn't have the method `someFunc`. So I just add @ts-ignore on top of that line to get around the compiler error.